# Wso2 asp net web api management

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, wso2-api-manager, restful-architecture

Morning Guys

I've been trying to manage an API created in asp.net WebApi, with the WSO2 Api Manager.

I've used the following doc with no sucess:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Create+and+Publish+an+API.

The sample shows the use of ".asmx" endpoint, and in my case I have a simple http url (http://sample.enterprise.com/api/TestService), I want to http get a jsont result by WSO2 using an url like this.

Any clues ?
Thanks

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking about here. Have you imported the swagger definition correctly? Have you specified the endpoint URL for your API (www.myDomain.com/api/myAPI/myResource implies the endpoint URL = www.myDomain.com/api/myApi/).

Comment: Sorry, I'm so new on this that I can't even make a decent question.
I've not imported the swagger, so I'll research on this. Thanks

Comment: I have managed to hit my api by applying your observations. Put it as an answer and I'll be happy to mark as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 documentation is not great. The link you provided guides you through **Designing** and Publishing an API, but nowhere do I see any explanation for publishing an existing API. You essentially have two choices:

1. Choose **Design New API** and define the resources exactly as they are defined in your existing API (name, action, and required parameters much match exactly). Once you reach the Implement tab, choose **Managed API** and provide the production endpoint for your API. If this sounds overly complicated, you also have...
2. Choose **I have an existing API** and import your API's swagger definition from file or API endpoint. Keep in mind that importing swagger directly from your API requires connections between your Publisher node and the API endpoint if you have a distributed API Manager deployment strategy.

You can find tools to help you generate a swagger definition for your APIs [here](http://swagger.io/). For Web API projects like ours, you might want to consider using [swashbuckle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle) from the nuGet repository.